# Python requests - Put ignores file upload

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to upload a file through python requests using the PUT method. But on the server side, the file is never received.

The code that I am using is:

```
files = {'test' : open(r"C:\Users\test.jar", 'rb')}

response = session.put(api_base + url.get('url').format(foo, bar),
                                headers=headers, data=data, files=files)
```

Does PUT ignore file uploads? Is it only valid for posts?

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Have you tried it via POST? In http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files it's only illustrated by POST e.g.

Comment: What are `foo` and `bar` replacing in your string format?

Comment: you should use requests.put instead

Comment: @colidyre my rest api only supports PUT

Comment: @dilkash what is the difference?

Comment: @Nordle They are path parameters

Comment: @ng.newbie What's your `data`?

Comment: @blhsing just simple string params like {'foo':'bar'}

Comment: @ng.newbie what I mean is that it looks as if you're using string formatting but not on a string with placeholders, unless `url.get('url')` returns a string that contains 2 '{}' that would eventually be replaced by the `.format(foo, bar)`

Comment: @Nordle Yes it returns a string with 2 {}.

Comment: @ng.newbie : is curl working? `curl http://service_adress --upload-file yourfile.txt` or `curl -X PUT -T "yourfile.txt" "http://service_adress"`

Comment: @colidyre yes Curl works

Comment: So I think it's a limitation on python's request module, that file upload (multipart-encoded-files) is only supported by POST and not PUT. Maybe you can try also that: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#custom-verbs -- never tried this, could help...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Python's request module does not work for file uploads if you use the PUT method as you did. The [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files) only shows one way to use POST requests. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not working intentionally.

Others also have problems using PUT requests for file transfer, see e.g:

- [Cannot PUT file to Django REST API by python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021629/cannot-put-file-to-django-rest-api-by-python-requests)
- [Python requests PUT method creates a zero byte file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882184/python-requests-put-method-creates-a-zero-byte-file)

OP moved to [PycURL](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html), which seems to work and also seems to be a good alternative.

Comment: Switched to pycurl.